# apache mod rewrite url not working with slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When i use:

```
mydomain.com/home
```

Everything works fine.
How ever when i use

```
mydomain.com/home/
```

i get "Internal Server Error"
im using

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I already tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

how ever it does not work,
I would like it also to work if i put a / behind the url.

Comment: Is `home` a real directory? Also are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava home is a php file ... thats what the current rewrite does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure there is no other code in your .htaccess when you test this.

Comment: works partly, when i go to /home/ the css is broken  but not broken on /home

Comment: i guess i can fix this my self... now it thinks the  assets are in /home/assets when its just in /assets

Comment: For that you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`